# Vuepress run built project

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I built a simple vuepress project with pwa support. Vuepress so far does only provide two scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "docs:dev": "vuepress dev docs",
    "docs:build": "vuepress build docs"
  }
```

The dev scripts works fine and I can check my web app locally, but I would like to check the app which my build script provides. The documentation of vuepress does not provide this information.

How can I run the build script and run afterwards the built app locally (in my case to check the pwa)

Answer (score 0):

Once built, the output is located in `<your-vuepress-project>/src/.vuepress/dist`. To serve it, install http-server (`npm install http-server`) and then run `http-server ./src/vuepress/dist` from your project folder.

Note that this requires you to have installed node.js